# Mysql trigger checking the value before inserting

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger, that checks a value before inserting it to the table, but I am getting an error in syntax I don't know where is a mistake.
My code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON payment for EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF(NEW.sum > 0)
 THEN INSERT INTO payment (sum) VALUE (NEW.sum);
 endif;
 end;
```

> Error I get:  "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 6"

Edit: Fixing it to end if; didn't help

Comment: (1) Syntax error - `END IF` must contain a space. (2) Logical error - the operations with the table which the trigger is defined on are not allowed except altering NEW columns values.

Comment: Trigger not needed. Add CHECK constraint into the table structure instead. `... , sum INT NOT NULL CHECK (sum > 0), ...`.

Comment: I need to use triggers for my task, so constraint is not an option :/

Comment: I fail to grasp what this trigger is supposed to do - if it did work and sum was less than or equal to zero the insert which fired the trigger would go ahead anyway. If you only want to SET sum (and BTW sum is a terrible name for a column) then I would test the opposite and SET new.sum = old.value or something else to cater for new.sum <= 0 otherwise just go ahead. Or SIGNAL a warning.

Comment: I guess my idea is to check the value before inserting and if it doesn't meet my rules, for this example sum cannot be zero, it the entry should not be added to the table.

Comment: And what else should happen - let it fail blind, produce a warning , reject and log...?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER test1
BEFORE INSERT
ON payment 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.sum <= 0 THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '`sum` value must be above zero.';
END IF;
END;
```